# Jquery on change not firing for dynamic content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a cascade dropdown with all dynamic elements.

My Html:

```
 <select id="Sites" name="SelectedSiteId"><option value=""></option></select>
 <select id="Sectors" name="SelectedSectorId"><option value=""></option></select>
```

I have 2 functions to load elements using ajax, both working fine:

```
function GetSites() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Sites/GetSites',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert("An error ocurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = "";
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Sites").html(items);
            }
        });
    }

    function GetSectors(siteId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Sites/GetSectors',
            data: { siteId: siteId },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert("An error ocurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = "";
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Sectors").html(items);
            }

        });
    }
```

I need to call GetSectors based on the Site selection. I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                       
        $("#Sites").on("change", function (e) {
            var siteId = $("#Sites").val();
            GetSectors(siteId);                
        });

        GetSites();
    });
```

But it doesn't work. I'm using jquery 1.8.3.

Any Idea where is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: @undefined similar questions are asked n times on a daily basis. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, unfortunately :)

Comment: Maybe we should have a canonical question for event delegation, if we don't already.

Comment: I spent some time looking in the n questions asked before but couldn't find the answer sorry.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try **Event Delegation**:

```
$(document).on("change", "#Sites", function(){
    var siteId = this.value;
    GetSectors(siteId);  
});
```

> The bubbling behavior of events allows us to do "event delegation" —
>   **binding handlers to high-level elements, and then detecting which
>   low-level element initiated the event.**
>
> Event delegation has two main benefits. **First**, it allows us to **bind
>   fewer event handlers** than we'd have to bind if we were listening to
>   clicks on individual elements, which can be **a big performance gain**.
>   **Second**, it allows us to **bind to parent elements** — such as an unordered
>   list — and know that our event handlers will **fire as expected even if
>   the contents of that parent element change.**

Taken from: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events

> Delegated events have the advantage that **they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.** This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, **so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.**

Taken from: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but still not working. I was wondering if it is related to one of the scripts MVC4 add, like jquery.unobstrusive-ajax, jquery-validate or jquery.validate.unobstrusive but I dont think so.

Comment: yes, and if I just call the method GetSectors(1) it works fine

Comment: Can you add an `alert` or a `console.log` inside the change event to make sure that the event is firing and that the value is present...something like `alert(this.value);` inside the event should work fine.

Comment: already try and nothing happens, I'm looking in Firebug to see if I can find something wrong

Comment: Well looks like my browser was not working properly, I just restart the browser and works! thanks a lot!

Comment: @estebane97 might have something to do with your cache

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on binding change function for dynamically added content. I solved it using this. Hope it helps someone ^^

```
$(".select_class").live("change", function(){
   console.log("testing...");
});
```

Comment: Please don't use ".live". This is used to help in converting from older jQuery event methods and were replaced in Typescript 1.7 by "$().on"  https://api.jquery.com/on/