# Do something when user changes the selection on select-option using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `Layout page` called `Layout.cshtml`
On that page I have a `div` whose ID is `friendsList`

I have a `View` called `Users.cshtml`
On that page I have a `select tag` whose ID is `AllowedFriends` and its value comes from the database

Now, I need to `add` that `AllowedFriends` to `friendsList`, so I write the JQuery as below

```
$("#friendsList").append($("#AllowedFriends"));
```

Upto here it is fine.

Now I want to show an alert or do something when `user changes the selection` on `AllowedFriends`.

So I write the JQuery as below :

```
$("#AllowedFriends").change(function () {
 // do something
});
```

But this does not work. I have tried to debug it. I used break point but this event never executes.

Comment: See the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346954/jquery-on-change-not-firing-for-dynamic-content

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answer. And also there was some problem with my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your created the element after, you need to use [`ON`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("change", "#AllowedFriends", function(){
 // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your event handler is bound to the element even if it doesn't exist in the DOM yet when the handler is declared. This is best achieved by working off the `document` object as we are assured it will always exist at the time of the event handler declaration:

```
 $(document).on("change", "#AllowedFriends", function(){
     //Glorious code!
  });
```

This is `event delegation`, and in simple terms it means that elements higher up the DOM tree listen for events that bubble up from its descendents (in this case, `document` is listening to the change event on its descendent element with the ID of `#AllowedFriends`

Answer (score 1):

Event delegation my friend:

```
$("#friendsList").on("change", "#AllowedFriends", function () {
    // do something
});
```